# Criar uma classe em javascript chamada idade que calcule a idade de uma pessoa a partir do ano de nascimento e ano atual

Tags: javascript, funções, classes

Essa classe foi elaborada de forma correta ou há algum erro seguindo o enunciado ?

```
imput = require("prompt-sync")();

class Idade{

    constructor(anoNascimento, anoAtual, idade){
        this.anoNascimento = anoNascimento;
        this.anoAtual = anoAtual;
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    setAnoNascimento(){
        return this.anoNascimento;
    }
    setAnoAtual(){
        return this.anoAtual;
    }
    calcularIdade(){
        this.idade = this.anoAtual - this.anoNascimento;
    }
}
var p1 = new Idade(1990,2022);
p1.calcularIdade();
console.log(p1);
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que o "ano atual" do enunciado você teria que pegar realmente o ano atual e não utilizar um valor já fixo (2022 que você especificou no construtor). Assim como a idade que também deve ser calculada, e não especificada.

Então, acho melhor utilizar o objeto `Date` do JavaScript para pegar o ano atual, e daí fazer a conta: `anoAtual - anoNascimento = idade`.

```js
class Idade{
    constructor(anoNascimento){
        const anoAtual = (new Date()).getFullYear();
        this.anoNascimento = anoNascimento;
        this.idade = anoAtual - anoNascimento;
    }
    
    setAnoNascimento(anoNascimento){
        const anoAtual = (new Date()).getFullYear();
        this.anoNascimento = anoNascimento;
        this.idade = anoAtual - anoNascimento;
    }
}

var p1 = new Idade(1990);
console.log(p1);
```